# Loading Excel file sheets case-insensitively

Tags: stata

I am simply converting Excel files into `dta` files:

```
foreach Var1 in Book1 Book2 {
    foreach Var2 in Sheet1 Sheet2 {
        import excel using "`Var1'.xls", sheet(`Var2') firstrow clear
    }
}
```

However, this does not work because of case sensitivity.

Book1 has sheets "Sheet1" and "Sheet2", while, Book2 has sheets "sheet1" and "sheet2". That is, sheet names are written in small letters.

How can I change my code to work for both capital and small letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
foreach Var1 in Book1 Book2 {
    import excel using "`Var1'.xls", describe
    forvalues i = 1 / `=r(N_worksheet)' {
        local nwks `nwks' `r(worksheet_`i')'
    }
    foreach Var2 of local nwks {
        import excel using "`Var1'.xls", sheet(`Var2') firstrow clear
    }
    local nwks
}
```